# Make Slide in Animation JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, slide

How would one make a slide and fade in animation like in seen in the green and pink boxes on [sharethis.com](http://www.sharethis.com)? In particular I like the one in the blue box with the arrows. Are there a set of JavaScript codes or CSS effects?

Comment: with much training and practice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would probably be to use a library like this:

http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/

I see that for the arrows effect the css-height property is animated when you scroll. This is done in javascript. But you can also achieve this effect through CSS3-transitions.

**Update:** Slide and wipe effects from the demo page:

```
// ani
var pinani = new TimelineMax()

// wipe
.add(TweenMax.to("#wipe", 1, {
    width: "100%"
}))
// slide
.add(TweenMax.to("#slide", 1, {
    top: "0%",
    ease: Bounce.easeOut,
    delay: 0.2
}));

// pin
new ScrollScene({
    triggerElement: "section#pin",
    duration: 1100
})
.on("progress", function () {
    // keep centered even though width changes
    $("#wipe h3").width($("#pin>h3").width());
})
    .setTween(pinani)
    .setPin("section#pin")
    .addTo(controller);
```

Comment: Do you know of any scroll magic tutorials. I especially like the slide and wipe effects but I can't find any instructions on how to make them. I'm sure I could just play around with it, but to have a tutorial to go by would really help make the most of the library and would be a lot more efficient.

Comment: Have you checked out the examples? (http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/examples/index.html) There's a "view source" link in all of them, and they're fairly good documented. If you start with the basic ones and work your way up, you should get a fairly good idea :)

Comment: I looked at every example but they didn't mention the slide and wipe effects

Comment: If you inspect the source on the demo page (F12), it looks like the slide and swipe effects are tweens. I'll update my answer in a bit.

Comment: It says something about using the minified version for demployment. Does that mean I should use the .min.js or just the .js or both?

Comment: Just one of them. They're the same code, it's just that the .min version have removed all comments and unecessary white-space etc., so that the file is smallest possible. That way the users won't have to download as much data when viewing your site:)